# How do i hide div element when clicking outside table? js

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I know there are other posts like this and i have looked through them but I still didn't manage to get it working.

What I am trying to do is to close all `div` tags inside a table i have.
The table looks like this.

```
  <table id='leads-table'>
     <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

So when i click outside `leads-table` i want `description-table div`(not the class `desc-class`) to get the `display='none'`. I managed to get this far writing in js. I would like the solution to be in js only please.

```
window.onload = function(){
var hideMe = document.getElementById('description-table').getElementsByTagName('DIV');
var descClass = document.getElementsByClassName('desc-class');

document.onclick = function(e){

 if(e.target.id = 'leads-table' && hideMe[0].style.display == 'block' ){
    
  hideMe[0].style.display == 'none';
 }
 else if(e.target.id != 'leads-table' && hideMe[0].style.display == 'block'){
    
  hideMe[0].style.display == 'none';
 }
 
 };
};
```

Comment: Do you have only one tr, which contains a div? If there is more than one, you can't use the id for this operation. if(e.target.id = 'leads-table' ... is wrong, use "==" or "===". Your if-elseif statement is weird. Whole block is the same as if(hideMe[0].style.display == 'block') {hideMe[0].style.display == 'none';} You need to fix those things and give some more details of your table structure. Then we can find a solution.

Comment: You can add a background with a element and onclick the background, do JS or use visibility or z-index (simple answer)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. To answer your questions, yes i do have multiple tr. You can visit this site [link](https://kantur.se/leads) if you want to see how the structure is. Maybe it's easier like this if you can actaully see the product! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what you need.

HTML:

```
<table id='leads-table'>
     <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
const hideMe = document.querySelectorAll('.desc-class');
const table = document.querySelector('table');

document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  if(e.target!==table){
    hideMe.forEach(aDiv=>{
      aDiv.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complex table version of the same thing:

HTML:

```
<table id='leads-table'>
     <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
       <td id='description-table'>
         <div class='desc-class'>
           Ah yes
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

JS:

```
const hideMe = document.querySelectorAll('.desc-class');
const table = document.querySelector('table');

document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  if(e.target!==table){
    hideMe.forEach(aDiv=>{
      aDiv.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solutions but for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe if you visit the site that i am working on you guys can see it better. [link](https://kantur.se/leads)